# deprecated runtime error 

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is `ereg` deprecated in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078993/why-is-ereg-deprecated-in-php)

I was uploading files to server but I got the following error

```
Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /home/vicedu/public_html/includes
/functions/sessions.php on line 112
```

What can I do? Please help

Comment: A deprecated function is one which is supposed to avoid and a better replacement of that function exists in the language library, in your case you should use preg_replace() instead of ereg_replace(), You can see docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Please point out why none of the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ereg+deprecated helped solve your question.

Comment: definite duplicate of [Why is `ereg` deprecated in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078993/why-is-ereg-deprecated-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to `preg_replace` since `eregi` has been deprecated, and update your pattern Since the `preg_*` variant is PCRE syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The function ereg_replace() is deprecated that mean superseded and should be avoided form php in replace of ereg_replace() you can use preg_replace. this will definately solve your problem.

Comment: It has not been removed...yet. Just strongly disapproved of.